# Creating a list of random elements using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, random

I was asked to define a recursive function that takes in two parameters:

- `n`
- `valmax`

  and **returns a list** of `n` numbers picked randomly from the interval `[0 , valmax]`

`

```
import random

def random_list(n, valmax, lst = []):
    """
    parameters : n of type int;
                 valmax of type int;
    returns    : a list of n numbers picked randomly from the interval 
                 [0, valmax]
    """
    if len(lst) == n:     
        return lst
    return [random.randint(0, valmax)] + random_list(n, valmax)

print(random_list(10,100))`
```

However, I'm getting an

> RecursionError

How can I fix my code so that it returns a list with `n` random numbers in the interval `[0, valmax]` ?

Comment: you are trying to slice lst in your recursive step, but the list is empty at first. you may want to rethink if you'd want to slice it in the first place.

Comment: Do you want to allow repetitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is wrong. You need each function call to return `n` random integers, so you do not need to pass it in a list.

Each function generates a single random number in the range `[0, valmax]` and concatenates it to the random list of integers which is of length one less (`n-1`) which it gets from calling itself recursively.

The base case is when `n == 1`, in which case we return an empty list.

```
import random
def random_list(n, valmax):
    if n == 0:
        return []
    return [random.randint(0, valmax)] + random_list(n-1, valmax)
```

and a test:

```
random_list(10, 20)
#[20, 9, 4, 7, 3, 4, 3, 18, 19, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of keeping a default parameter (which can also cause [unexpected behavior on consecutive calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)), use `yield` for a cleaner solution. Also, simply use `random.randint(0, valmax)` to generate a single random integer between `0` and `valmax`:

```
import random
def random_list(n, valmax):
  if n:
    yield random.randint(0, valmax)
    yield from random_list(n-1, valmax)

print(list(random_list(10, 10))) #create a list of length ten with random values between 0 and 10, inclusive.
```

Output:

```
[4, 6, 9, 1, 10, 2, 2, 8, 2, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a generic `build_list` function -

```
import random

def identity (x):
  return x

def build_list (size, proc = identity):
  if size == 0:
    return []
  else:
    return build_list (size - 1, proc) + [ proc (size - 1) ]

print (build_list (5))
# [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

print (build_list (5, lambda _: random.randint (0, 10)))
# [ 4, 7, 7, 3, 6 ]
```

`random_list` could be a specialization of `build_list` -

```
def random_list (size, valmax):
  return build_list (size, lambda _: random.randint (0, valmax))

print (random_list (5, 10))
# [ 1, 7, 4, 7, 0 ]
```